# Audio doesn't play in Opera, at all, and is this a common issue?

Tags: html, audio, mp3, opera

I'm trying to play an mp3 in opera. It doesn't work. It's just an mp3, no code or anything. I get this error "the procedure entry point libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks could not be lovated in the dynamic link library libvlc.dll"

I'm afraid that this might be normal for Opera (I just installed it), so I'd like to figure out what the problem is and if there's any way in HTML to get around this problem. At the very least, I'd like to have a popup or other notification that let's the user know how to solve the problem (maybe download a plugin or something similar).

Comment: No, Opera can play mp3 files. If the system can. How are you trying to play it? Got a fiddle?

Comment: This this link in Opera: http://fallowproduction.com/music/Paradigm%20E%20-%20Once%20upon%20a%20Dubstep2.mp3 -- It gives me an error.

Comment: If I just put that in the location bar, it plays fine. Does it play in other browsers on your computer? If so, which plugins do you have? To be honest, I'm not sure I could solve it if it wasn't working...

Comment: That's reassuring. My browser must be messed up, which is strange considering I just downloaded it recently. Maybe it has something to do with VLC? Either way, that's good to know. Am I right that Opera and Safari (latest versions) both support HTML5? It plays fine on IE, Chrome, and Firefox. It's a bigger issue if it's not just my computer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about the latest version of Safari. Because I don't have a Mac, and Apple stopped making Safari for other platforms over a year ago!

Comment: That might be the reason. I downloaded it from here: http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1531 and it says it was posted in 2012, but apparently the version is from 2007. I'm not sure why my Opera's messed up, but at least it's not specifically an Opera problem.

Comment: 2007? No, that doesn't sound right. The 5.1.7 files are all dated April 25, 2012. Which date did you look at?

Comment: At the wikipedia of Safari version history (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history). It looks like they just ported it to Windows 8 in 2012